# Maven and multiple customer customizations

Tags: java, maven, enterprise

I'm working with an application that is used both internally and externally in our company to test APIs (ranging from simple REST APIs to proprietary binary protocols). Each customer/customer project that is using the application can have multiple APIs/protocols and versions of those. This means that we need to have a specific build for each customer.

So far we have done this by having a core component that is used as a maven dependency by all customers. We then started needing more complex build setups for the customer builds and decided to have a common parent pom for all customer projects resulting in this structure.

```
            _customer1_
           /           \
parentPom /             \_ coreProject
          \             /
           \_customer2_/
```

This was fine as long as our APIs and protocols used SNAPSHOTS during development and we only had to change versions manually in each customer pom when there had been a release for that customer (at most once a month for each customer).
But recently some APIs have migrated to create a new non-SNAPSHOT version at least once a day. Now, this has become untenable as we can have multiple versions in a single day.

Each customer project has its own parent pom which contains all the relevant version information for each API/protocol. However, if we were to use this pom as the parent for our customer project we lose the reusability of our own commonly defined build steps.

One solution that we tried was to keep doing what we were doing but add a new module to the customer project that used, for instance, the fat customer1 jar as a dependency, but then added the correct APIs/protocols on top of that.

This did not work... We're facing a ton of classloader issues and need to find another solution.

As maven does not support multiple parents that is not a solution. Including our config in some common parent pom shared by all customers is not feasible. Manually copying all build steps is something we're trying to avoid as we don't want to maintain that.

I can't imagine that we are the only ones with this problem, but I keep coming back to a feeling of us missing the root-cause of this as I can't find any available solution.

So if you are an enterprise-maven-wizard, please share your wisdom!

Answer (score 0):

We have a pretty big Maven multi-project creating several apps which share lots of code and libs (we do ship the same product to the customers though).

We have a Parent POM where we set repositories and control the dependency versions (dependencyManagement). We have one core module (jar) which has common code/features used by all applications. 
All applications extend the parent POM and import the core module: what is generic is pushed to the core (I am simplifying here) while application-specific code (could be the customer for you?) is in the application Maven sub-project, where we get the flexibility to customise/adjust as we need.

In this way we have lots of POMs with the same version, we create a WAR file for each app so they can be deployed independently.
The version update is done with Maven Release Plugin.

I am sure there are other ways but we have run this model for years without huge problems, what it is critical it is not create cyclic dependency between the sub-projects.

Comment: Yes, that would be the customer in our situation. What makes it difficult in our situation is that the application-specific code will depend on other projects with their own versioning. :/